# How to clear the input of file chooser component on command line in install4j?

Tags: java, install4j

The file chooser component always preserve the previous results on command line, just like

```
example file:
[/bin/example/file.txt]
```

If I enter a "space" or "Enter" key, the previous value "/bin/exampel/file.txt" will be chose. If I input another path, the value of "example file" will be changed, but how to empty the value of "example file" without changing my code? It's an easy thing in Windows, but I couldn't find anything that works in Linux.

If it's necessary to change my code, all I can think of is when the user input a specific string such as "[]", I call

```
context.setVariable("file chooser variable", null);
```

to clear the input manually, which doesn't seem very reasonable.

Is there any better method to clear the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In console mode, the empty string or a blank string signifies the acceptance of the default value, there is no way to interpret it as missing input.

You could use a "Console handler" form component to ask the questions yourself with something like this:

```
console.println("Current directory: " + context.getVariable("fileVariableName"));
if (console.askYesNo("Enter a different directory?")) {
    String newDirectory = console.askString("New directory", "");
    if (newDirectory.trim().isEmpty()) {
        context.setVariable("fileVariableName", null);
    } else {
        context.setVariable("fileVariableName", new File(newDirectory));
    }
}

return true;
```

Then set the "Visibility script" property of the file chooser component to `!context.isConsole()` so it is not displayed in console mode.

Comment: Hi @Ingo, I found if I didn't set the "Visibility script" property of the file chooser component whose variable is `fileVariableName` to `!context.isConsole() `, and add the "Console handler" to reset the variable `fileVariableName`, this `reset` would not work. Is it because Install4j preferentially selects the values set by the `file chooser` over the values obtained from `Console handler`?

Comment: No, it should just be a matter of ordering of the form components. i.e. the last one wins

Comment: I did some tests, I placed `file chooser` before the `Console handler`, the value of `fileVariableName` was both changed in these two components, when we left the setting page, the value of  `fileVariableName` was the one set in the `file chooser`, it's strange.